# How to reference the SPI1 Data Register in plain english for DMA setup in Rust

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32

I am trying to use the Rust language to code for an STM32 bluepill.  I am using the `STM32f1xx_hal` crate which subsequently calls the `STM32f1` crate for the peripherals. What I would like to do is use more natural language to specify the peripheral address for the DMA target memory location vice hardcode the address.

This is what is looks like to hard code the address:

`dp.DMA1.ch3.par.write(|w| unsafe { w.bits(0x4001_3000 + 0x0c) } );`

This is what I wanted to do:

`dp.DMA1.ch3.par.write(|w| &dp.SPI1.dr as *const _);`

I of course get errors for this.

`expected mutable reference, found *-ptr`

I am very new to this (both embedded programming and using Rust) and am most likely getting something totally wrong.  Is there somebody here who can point me in the right direction.  Thanks in advance.  I also totally realize that this may be the incorrect forum.  If so, let me know and I will shift my question over there.

Answer (score 0):

First, you're using the PAC (peripheral access crate) API here, which is powerful, but low-level and error-prone. [`stm32f1xx-hal`](https://crates.io/crates/stm32f1xx-hal) has a [DMA API](https://docs.rs/stm32f1xx-hal/0.3.0/stm32f1xx_hal/dma/index.html). The repository has a number of [examples that use it](https://github.com/stm32-rs/stm32f1xx-hal/tree/master/examples).

If that HAL API suits your needs, then I'd just use that instead.

As for your actual question, you're on the right track, but not quite there.

First, the approach that you're using to write to the register is wrong:

```rust
dp.DMA1.ch3.par.write(|w| &dp.SPI1.dr as *const _);
```

The `write` method takes a closure, which gives you the `w` argument and expects you to return the same `w`. The `w` argument is of type [`&mut dma1::ch::par::W`](https://docs.rs/stm32f1/0.7.1/stm32f1/stm32f103/dma1/ch/par/struct.W.html), and the closure expects you to return the same thing. What you've written returns your `const` pointer instead, which is what the error message complains about.

What you need to do is to use the API provided by the [`W`](https://docs.rs/stm32f1/0.7.1/stm32f1/stm32f103/dma1/ch/par/struct.W.html) type to write to the register. I haven't tested the following, but based on the documentation, it (or something close to it) should work:

```rust
dp.DMA1.ch3.par.write(|w| w.pa().bits(&dp.SPI1.dr as *const _ as u32));
```

> I also totally realize that this may be the incorrect forum. If so, let me know and I will shift my question over there.

I don't think this is the *incorrect* forum, but there might be a few better ones. A lot of people hang out on the `rust-embedded` channel on Matrix. Off the top of my head, I don't know of a good link to point beginners to, but here's [a direct link to the channel](https://riot.im/app/#/room/#rust-embedded:matrix.org). You can probably figure it out :-)

Another good possibility is the [embedded category on the Rust Users forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/c/embedded).